# Is there any size limitation data of curl what return?

Tags: php, curl, cakephp

I have faced a big problem. I am using `curl` function to hit browser. I am getting data using `curl` function.

Here is my `curl function` **requestToAvr**

```
public function requestToAvr($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 512);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,3);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

When I use below code I get value what I want.

```
$url_data           = "http://192.168.20.128/?cmd={sid:123,fnc:201,val:[188,24910,3]}";
$ret_data           = $this->requestToAvr($url_data);
```

And `$ret_data` value looks like this **{sid:1234,{mid:123,fnc:201,sts:[3,030b0600000689000000E000E401FF04D231F5]}}**

But when I use below code I don't get any value. And `pr($ret_data)` print empty

```
$url_data           = "http://192.168.20.128/?cmd={sid:123,fnc:201,val:[188,24910,5]}";
$ret_data           = $this->requestToAvr($url_data);
```

But when I hit this url `http://192.168.20.128/?cmd={sid:123,fnc:201,val:[188,24910,5]}` direct browser it shows me the below value in browser body.

**{sid:1234{mid:123,fnc:201,sts[5,050b3000CF00C000D300D100CF00CF00D100CF00CF00CF00D100CF00CF00D100CF00CF00D100CF00CE00D300D100D100CF00CFDF8D]}}**

So how can I get value using `curl function`?? I also use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 512);`to increase buffer size. Am I wrong?? Is there any alternative function what is fixed my problem??

Any idea or suggestion please.

Comment: How is this related to CakePHP? In any case make sure that you check the exact type of the return value (it might be `false`, which prints as "nothing"), and that you check for possible cURL errors: **http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php**

Comment: @ndm, this is my `Cakephp` project and I submit those code what is related about my problem. `Cakephp` is not fact. Fact is my problem, how can I fix it?? Thanks for your recommendation

Comment: Are you still having an issue? If not, what did you do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your `requestToAvr()` function, add a `var_dump($result)`. Is the function being called correctly? If `$result` is false, check [`curl_error($ch)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php), and echo/log the error. It's likely that your PHP machine can't access `192.168.20.128`, or the output is different when being accessed by curl (Perhaps the remote server is providing differing/blank output because the request header looks like it's coming from an automated source).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind information. I have solved this issue socket connection.

Comment: @A.ANoman Can you share your insight into the problem, and what caused it for future readers?